# Can't open link containing special characters

Tags: javascript, html, django, hyperlink, attachment

I have Django app which I test on my local PC and then when I add something new, I upload changes to my company virtual server. I have a problem with links to files. Below is the code for links to attached files (both my local and server have the same code):

```
<p class="article-content mt-2 mb-1"><strong>Attachment: </strong><a href="{{post.file_close.url}}">{{post.file_close.name}}</a></p>
```

If I upload file `cars.png` everything works fine in both versions. This works no matter the extension, pdf, excel, image, etc.
Problem is, if I upload file `carsčč.png` it fails only on server side, on my PC it works great.
I get the following error on my Django/debugg:

```
Page not found (404)
“C:\inetpub\files\PyWeb\media\PN_files\2022\03\06\cars” does not exist
```

Url of the error page is:

```
http://hidden_part/media/PN_files/2022/03/06/carsčč.png
```

But when I click copy and paste it's like this:

```
http://hidden_part/media/PN_files/2022/03/06/cars%C4%8D%C4%8D.png
```

Like the link is not complete, it stopped as soon as it runs into a special character.
But, shown link still containes all the letters, it's `PN_files/2022/03/06/carsčč.png`
Tried:
I looked at regional settings, it's the same on both PCs. Is there something else I could check or change? Maybe include something in the link?
Also, when I manually search for the file, the name is not currupted, it's saved localy as `carsčč.png`. So I guess it's only the link, tring to get the file.
I figured out it's because of diacritic letters. On my 'base.html' I have `meta charset="utf-8"`. Django setting `LANGUAGE_CODE = 'hr-BA'`.

I use Bootstrap 4.0 `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

Server is hosted on Windows, IIS, .NET Globalization settings are set to utf-8.

Comment: Which storage backend are you using?

Comment: Not sure what it means, but I have a file field in my models.py:
```file_close = models.FileField(blank=True, upload_to='PN_files/%Y/%m/%d/', verbose_name="Attachment", validators=[validate_file_size], help_text="Max size 50MB")```
And all files are stored localy on the same server.

Answer (score 0):

In line `<a href="{{post.file_close.url}}">` you are internally calling the url() method of the underlying Storage class, which returns the wrong url `“C:\inetpub\files\PyWeb\media\PN_files\2022\03\06\cars”`.

The main problem is within your storage class. You are propably using `FileSystemStorage` from django. Whenever you are saving a file, the storage class is calling `storage.get_valid_name`, which is returning a name which is suitable to use on the target system ([ref](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/files/storage/#django.core.files.storage.Storage.get_valid_name)). In this step the special characters are replaced. The code provided on Storage retains only alpha-numeric characters, periods and underscores from the original filename, removing everything else ([ref](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/custom-file-storage/#django.core.files.storage.get_valid_name))The code provided on Storage retains only alpha-numeric characters, periods and underscores from the original filename, removing everything else.).

If you want to change this behaviour, you could write your own custom storage class and overwrite the `get_valid_name` method ([ref](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/custom-file-storage/#django.core.files.storage.get_valid_name)).

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer, but why does the same code work on my PC and not on server? I can upload any file regarding of name on my PC, but not on server django app?

Comment: This is impossible to say, without knowing your PC and Server configuration.  Maybe someone else can guess.